# Makefile automatic dependency not working with GNU Make 4.0 or later

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have created the following makefile with reference to [this site](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) to try out automatic dependency generation. My makefile works fine when I run it with GNU Make 3.81(the one that comes with macOS). However, if I run it with the newer version of GNU Make(4.3, installed via Homebrew), all the objects and dependency files get recreated every single time when I run make, even though there is no change in the source files.

```
CXX          := clang++
CXXFLAGS     := -Wall -Werror -std=c++11
ICUROOT      := ${HOME}/opt/icu4c
XERCESCROOT  := ${HOME}/opt/xercesc
CPPFLAGS     := -I$(ICUROOT)/include -I$(XERCESCROOT)/include
LDFLAGS      := -lxerces-c -licuuc
LDLIBS       := -L$(ICUROOT)/lib -L$(XERCESCROOT)/lib
OBJDIR       := obj
DEPDIR       := $(OBJDIR)/.deps
DEPFLAGS      = -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.d

SRCS = $(wildcard *.cpp)


.PHONY: all
all: DOMPrint

COMPILE.cc = $(CXX) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPDIR)/%.d | $(DEPDIR)
    $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

$(DEPDIR): ; @mkdir -p $@

DEPFILES := $(SRCS:%.cpp=$(DEPDIR)/%.d)
$(DEPFILES): ;

DOMPrint: $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,DOMPrint.o DOMPrintFilter.o DOMPrintErrorHandler.o DOMTreeErrorReporter.o)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^


-include $(wildcard $(DEPFILES))
```

Debugging information printed from `make --debug`(partial), it shows that the dependency file is newer than the target, and the object file is rebuilt:

```
GNU Make 4.3
Built for arm-apple-darwin21.1.0
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Reading makefiles...
Updating makefiles....
Updating goal targets....
 File 'all' does not exist.
     Prerequisite 'obj/.deps/DOMPrintErrorHandler.d' is newer than target 'obj/DOMPrintErrorHandler.o'.
    Must remake target 'obj/DOMPrintErrorHandler.o'.
clang++ -MT obj/DOMPrintErrorHandler.o -MMD -MP -MF obj/.deps/DOMPrintErrorHandler.d -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 -I/Users/chunwaichan/opt/icu4c/include -I/Users/chunwaichan/opt/xercesc/include  -c -o obj/DOMPrintErrorHandler.o DOMPrintErrorHandler.cpp
    Successfully remade target file 'obj/DOMPrintErrorHandler.o'.
...
```

However, looking at the last modified time in `make -p` output below(partial), the dependency file isn't newer than the object file, but the automatic variable `?` does show that it is newer.

```
obj/DOMPrintErrorHandler.o: DOMPrintErrorHandler.cpp obj/.deps/DOMPrintErrorHandler.d ...
#  Implicit rule search has been done.
#  Implicit/static pattern stem: 'DOMPrintErrorHandler'
#  Last modified 2022-01-08 10:50:25.517904773
#  File has been updated.
#  Successfully updated.
# automatic
# ? := obj/.deps/DOMPrintErrorHandler.d

obj/.deps/DOMPrintErrorHandler.d:
#  Implicit rule search has not been done.
#  Last modified 2022-01-08 09:45:13.890973263
#  File has been updated.
#  Successfully updated.
#  recipe to execute (from 'Makefile', line 32):
```

I have tested this makefile with GNU Make 3.81 till 4.3, starting from version 4.0, this issue happens. I would like to know what change/enhancement in the newer version of GNU Make has caused this issue and how can I fix my makefile to make it compatible.

Comment: Are you sure that the difference in behavior does not arise elsewhere, such as at the compiler?  Because my first inclination is to guess that `make` is right about the depfiles being newer than the object files, and therefore right (with respect to the makefile presented) to rebuild the object files.

Comment: Note also that the page you reference mentions that as a possible problem and presents a solution.  Scroll down to the "Handling unusual situations" section.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I run both GNU Make 3.81 and 4.3 in the same directory, makefile/compiler(clang++) is also the same. I will try `gcc` and see if it gives different result.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the behavior you see with the standard version of GNU make on my GNU/Linux system.  Here is a complete repro case that I used:

```
$ cat main.h
#define RET 0

$ cat main.cpp
#include "main.h"
int main() { return RET; }

$ cat Makefile
CXX          := g++
CXXFLAGS     := -Wall -Werror -std=c++11
CPPFLAGS     := -I.
OBJDIR       := obj
DEPDIR       := $(OBJDIR)/.deps
DEPFLAGS      = -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.d

COMPILE.cc = $(CXX) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c

SRCS = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJS = $(SRCS:%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
DEPS = $(SRCS:%.cpp=$(DEPDIR)/%.d)

all: main

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPDIR)/%.d | $(DEPDIR) ; $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

$(DEPDIR): ; @mkdir -p $@

$(DEPS): ;

main: $(OBJS) ; $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean: ; rm -rf obj main

-include $(wildcard $(DEPS))

$ make
g++ -MT obj/main.o -MMD -MP -MF obj/.deps/foo.d -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 -I.  -c -o obj/main.o main.cpp
g++ -Wall -Werror -std=c++11   -o main obj/main.o

$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

Also something odd: the output of my `make -p` does not show any automatic variables, as are shown in your example:

```
obj/main.o: main.cpp obj/.deps/main.d main.cpp main.h | obj/.deps
#  Implicit rule search has been done.
#  Implicit/static pattern stem: 'main'
#  Last modified 2022-01-08 14:18:05.5745307
#  File has been updated.
#  Successfully updated.
#  recipe to execute (from 'Makefile', line 19):
    $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

Maybe the version of GNU make you are using has some local changes?

If you download the vanilla GNU make source from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/ and compile that does it work properly?

Comment: I have tried using the vanilla GNU Make that I compile from source, still it doesn't work properly for GNU Make 4.0 or later.

Comment: It works fine if I change the compiler to `g++`, and I have also noticed that the generated dependency files are slightly different. There's a blank line after each rule in all the dependency files created by `clang++`. I have tried removing the blank lines manually with `sed -i '/^$/d' *.d` and update the object files' timestamp with `touch *.o` to make the object files newer than dependency files and run make again. The object files are no longer being rebuilt this time.

Comment: I cannot explain this: additional blank lines makes no difference: blank lines are ignored.  Certainly if `clang` writes out `.d` files with newer timestamps than the `.o` file that will cause this problem, no question about it... if that's true it's a bug in clang.  But there's no reason why this behavior would change between GNU make 3.82 and GNU make 4.0 so I can't explain why it works with older versions.

Comment: @bryccw, does not touching all the `*.o` files *by itself* cause `make` not to rebuild those files?  If so, then your test does not speak to whether differences in the depfiles are related to the issue you describe.

Comment: I assumed that they were modifying the compile rule to only touch the just-built object file after the compile was done.  But I see that I may have assumed too much.

Comment: It would be useful if my example above, exactly, was tested and if the incorrect behavior could be confirmed or denied with that simple test case, with different versions of GNU make and `clang++` vs `g++`.

Comment: @MadScientist @John You are right, this issue has nothing to do with the blank lines. The Apple `clang++` compiler writes out `.d` files with newer timestamp than the `.o` files when running with GNU Make 4.0. I did the same test on another Linux machine, it works fine for both `clang++` and `g++`.

Comment: @bryccw, If Apple `clang++` does that when running under GNU Make 4 then it is virtually certain that it does the same thing when invoked with the same command line and environment directly on the command line or by a different version of `make`.  The program would have to go *far* out of its way to do otherwise, and if it did, then I would account that a bug in `clang++`.  There's not much that `make` can do to influence that.

Comment: So if you think you really do see different behavior under different `make`s with everything else the same, and you want to figure out why (as opposed to simply finding a workaround), then that calls for some careful testing.  The next phase of that would be to determine *what else*, if anything, differs.  For example, version of `clang++`, environment in which it is invoked, *etc*..